# Angular 2+ i want to get option attribute

Tags: angular, html-select

How angular 2 form of select gets option attribute.
I have this code

```
<select style="width: 200px" (change)="lv3Change()" id="lv3" name="lv3" [(ngModel)]="lv3" >
          <option *ngFor="let tmp of lv3List; let i=index"
                 [value]="tmp.valueField [attr.index]="i">
            {{tmp.textField}}
          </option>
    </select>
```

how can I get attr.index  value as method: `lv3Change` param 
like this code :`(change)=lv3Change(attr.index)` it is not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(change)` is fired before `[(ngModel)]="..."` can update the model

Use instead

```
(ngModelChange)="lv3Change()"
```

or

```
(ngModelChange)="lv3Change($event)"
```

You can also try

```
(change)="lv3Change($event.target.value)"
```

but I'd discourage using that together with `[(ngModel)]="..."`